# Best way to return a vector in C++ function?

Tags: c++

Say I have this function:

```
vector<int> func(vector<int>& a) {
    vector<int> res;
    for (int x : a) {
        res.push_back(a*2);
    }
    return res;
}
```

As far as I'm aware, when `func` returns, `res` is copied onto the stack which basically repeats an O(n) operation. Does C++ have capabilities to return a vector here without copying the entire thing ?

Comment: Read about [copy elision](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) and [return value optimization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization)

Comment: **tl;dr** - There likely won't be a redundant copy. At most a (cheap, in this case) move.

Comment: For the specific function you show, I recommend you learn about [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transformer).

Comment: I see, so ignoring transform aside, the toy function doesn't require any changes to be optimized?

Comment: @doctopus You'd better call `reserve` before pushing items into the vector